# Spring cannot configure authorization server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I created a simple authorization server, but cannot configure it.

1. Start both apps (8080 is for auth server and 9999 is for client).
2. Go to `localhost:9999/client` and get redirected to `localhost:8080/login` (as expected).
3. Fill the login form with *user/user*.
4. Get redirected to `localhost:9999/client` (as expected), but have `Hello, null` instead of `Hello, user`.

However, if I go straight to `localhost:8080/me`, I have `{"name":"user"}`. How can I retrieve `Hello, user`?

**Authorization server**

```
@RestController
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping({ "/user", "/me" })
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
        return Collections.singletonMap("name", principal == null ? "null" : principal.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user").authorities(AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin();
    }
}
```

**Application's properties**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: clientid
      client-secret: clientsecret
      scope: read,write
      auto-approve-scopes: '.*'
```

**Client**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class Client {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Principal principal) {
        return "Hello, " + principal.getName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Client.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name=client").run(args);
    }

}
```

**Client's properties**

```
server:
  port: 9999
  context-path: /client
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: clientid
      client-secret: clientsecret
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/me
```

**UPDATE:**
I downloaded [a tutorial](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/auth-server) when all works, but it has [ssoFilter](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/blob/master/auth-server/src/main/java/com/example/SocialApplication.java#L81) that is only for OAuth2 authentication. I just want to configure it with `loginForm`.
I have also shared a temporary [example](https://github.com/delverdev/login-server-example) on GitHub. I think it will be easier to look up the problem with it.

Comment: How is your request ? including the headers

Comment: Just a guess, according to the UserDetailsService contract, a user has to have GrantedAuthorites or a UsernameNotFoundException will be thrown, try to give your user a role.

Comment: @OrtwinAngermeier, unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ports **9999** **8080** this will lead to the **cross-origin** HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain, or port than the one which the first resource itself serves.

For more details about **[HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)**

There is peaty good example on official spring site [Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

I would suggest to do CORS filter on your app simply by implementing Filter interface.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    public CorsFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //for production add only origins which should be allowed to access now for demo purposes this accepts all.
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE"); //i would reduce this method list if not all methods used this is added just for demo purposes
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

If you using spring boot app then be sure to **include the package** where your new filter created **in a component scan**.

If you using 'web.xml' for configuration:

then add filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mycompany.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

option **A** add mapping on your servlet

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

option **B** add filter for all apps:

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> <!--this will add cors on all apps-->
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: The filter filters on the login-server, but seems like it isn't the solution. I still have `Hello, null`.

Comment: Install fiddler or other tool which could print your HTTP communication. Or just use web developer tools by pressing F12 button, then go to network tab and take a look how your request is handled all HTTP packets should have 200 status codes. Please can you do the screenshot then I could see what's happening. I still believe that CORS issue if you haven’t changed to solve this.

Comment: I installed Fiddler. Here are the screenshots: [without filter](http://imgur.com/5Qzk9ik), [with filter](http://imgur.com/mlzpkXD). Seems that they're identical except the favicon.

Comment: also I forgot to mention that the issue isn't solved. I awarded the bounty because it was almost expired and I thought that it's really because of the CORS.

Answer (score 0):

The user details are loaded by `org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices`, so it would be worth adding a breakpoint in there to see what it's getting from your /me endpoint.

This class only extracts the basic user details, indeed looking at the code it seems to set a hard coded role of ROLE_USER, so you would be well advised to create your own implmentation of this to set up your `OAuth2Authentication` correctly for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code a little bit and it works locally for me.

```
@EnableOAuth2Client
@RestController
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@SpringBootApplication
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@GetMapping({"/user", "/me"})
public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
    return Collections.singletonMap("name", principal == null ? "null" : principal.getName());
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("user").authorities(AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/me").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.setOrder(-100);
    return registration;
}

private Filter authFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            path);
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
    filter.setRestTemplate(template);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(
            client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId());
    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(template);
    filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    return filter;
    }
}

class ClientResources {

@NestedConfigurationProperty
private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

@NestedConfigurationProperty
private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
    return client;
}

public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
    return resource;
    }
}
```

You need to register an authenticationTokenFilter and no need to register the ssoFilter.

Comment: I don't my authorization server to be a OAuth2 client, just want to use a simple form login.

Answer (score -1):

Because both your auth server and client are served from the same host (`localhost`) your web browser is probably confused as to which http endpoint belongs to which http cookie.

Try specifying one as `127.0.0.1` and the other as `localhost` so that your browser associates http cookies to their correct endpoints.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I downloaded [a tutorial](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/auth-server) when all works, but I can access it all with `localhost`.